# Adding additional IP addresses on windows server

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, scripting

Is it possible to use powershell or use a bat script under `C:\Windows\addExtraIP.bat` that uses a number of arguments to add IP addresses to the interface/connection.

The idea is to use something like:

`addExtraIP.bat 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.3 192.168.1.4 and so on..`

This `addExtraIP.bat` script should be called/invoked from remote. I read something about [PowerShell remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/running-remote-commands?view=powershell-5.1), but not sure where to start or what to do.

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

```
function Set-IPAddress {
        param(  [string]$networkinterface = "Local Area Connection",
            [string]$ip, 
            [string]$mask,
            [string]$gateway, 
            [string]$dns1 = "8.8.8.8",
            [string]$dns2 = "8.8.4.4",
            [string]$registerDns = "TRUE"
     )


     #Start writing code here
     $dns = $dns1
     if($dns2){$dns =$dns1,$dns2}
     $index = (gwmi Win32_NetworkAdapter | where {$_.netconnectionid -eq $networkinterface}).InterfaceIndex
     $NetInterface = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | where {$_.InterfaceIndex -eq $index}
     $NetInterface.EnableStatic($ip, $mask)
     $NetInterface.SetGateways($gateway)
     $NetInterface.SetDNSServerSearchOrder($dns)
     $NetInterface.SetDynamicDNSRegistration($registerDns)

 }

 Set-IPAddress
```

This script is what I am trying to use. How would I call the script as mentioned above?

EDIT 2:

```
function Set-IPAddress {
        param(
            [string]$networkinterface = "Local Area Connection",
            [string[]]$ip, 
            [string[]]$mask,
            [string]$gateway, 
            [string]$dns = @("10.210.1.101", "10.210.1.130"),
            [bool]$registerDns = $true
     )


     $index = (gwmi Win32_NetworkAdapter | where {$_.netconnectionid -eq $networkinterface}).InterfaceIndex
     $NetInterface = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | where {$_.InterfaceIndex -eq $index}
     $NetInterface.EnableStatic($ip, $mask)
     $NetInterface.SetGateways($gateway)
     $NetInterface.SetDNSServerSearchOrder($dns)
     $NetInterface.SetDynamicDNSRegistration($registerDns)

 }

 Set-IPAddress -IP '1.2.3.4', '2.3.4.5' -Mask '255.255.255.0', '255.255.255.0'
```

So how would I set this in a script and run regardless how much arguments are passed to it?

Comment: Yes, but it may be better to use a text file containing the IP addresses. If you don't post the current script you require help with, your question will be a straight code request and be off topic here.

Comment: Your question is very vague and contains no actual code so we have no idea what, or how, you are trying to do. You really need to read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) as this will help you figure out what your question is missing and why it's being downvoted.

Comment: I've made an update on the question. I understand the down votes but this whole Windows thing is new for me. It is once in long time that I need to use a windows machine. Again, the idea is to add multiple IP's to the interface just as Linux does using `eth0:1, eth0:2... ` and so on.

Comment: Take a look at [New-NetIPAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/new-netipaddress?view=win10-ps)

Comment: @JamesC. I see `New-NetIPAddress -InterfaceIndex 12 -IPAddress 192.168.0.1 -PrefixLength 24 -DefaultGateway 192.168.0.5` but how would I use a `for loop` and substitute `192.168.0.1` as parameter? Also this `ps1` script should be called remotely.

Comment: Not seeing any actual batch-file code, so not sure what you needed help with in that respect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic foreach loop using `New-NetIPAddress`:

```
param([array]$IPs)

Foreach ($IP in $IPs)
{
    New-NetIPAddress -InterfaceIndex 12 -IPAddress $IP -PrefixLength 24 -DefaultGateway 192.168.0.5
}
```

Then call like:

```
ScriptName.ps1 -IPs 192.168.0.1,192.168.0.2
```

Comment: Thank you! Going to have a look locally first. I finally need to call the script from a remote machine using `chef-knife`